# ThreadLocal and Task

Tags: c#, multithreading

I use a static ThreadLocal to cache some heavyweight objects. Consider the following code:

```
class MatchItemFinder
{
    private static ThreadLocal<PaddedImage> tempImage;
    MatchItemFinder()
    {
        if(tempImage==null) 
            tempImage = new ThreadLocal<PaddedImage>(
            () => new PaddedImage(patchSize, patchSize));
    }
    internal void DoSomething(){
        //Do something with tempImage.Value
    }
}
```

When DoSomething() is called from multiple Task Parallel Library threads, when each instance is created? I mean obviously threads are reused so is my **tempImage** created every time a thread is created or every time a thread is reused?

With a design perspective do you think this kind of caching would be a great decision or there are better strategies to cache large objects in a thread safe manner?

I'm using .Net 4.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854976/will-values-in-my-threadstatic-variables-still-be-there-when-cycled-via-threadpo

Comment: What is the goal of your cache?  Do you really want every thread to have its own copy of your large object?  Or are you really looking at sharing a *single* large object with all threads, but in a thread safe manner?  If it's the latter, have a look at the [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: @sstan You are asking the right question. I don't really want to have like 250 instances of large object. The ideal situation is to have as few instances as the number of concurrent threads that at a specific time are actually doing something on tempImages like 8 instances corresponding to 8 hyper threaded cores. Lazy doesn't do the job because it's not about initialization. The large objects are temporary images manipulated by DoSomething() so a single instance won't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread local variables do not cooperate with the TPL or with the thread pool. They are `Thread`-based. When any TPL library function reuses a thread your thread locals will be reused.

> With a design perspective do you think this kind of caching would be a great decision or there are better strategies to cache large objects in a thread safe manner?

If your cache items are immutable there is no need for thread local items. Use a global cache.

Comment: They objects are not immutable, They are manipulated in DoSomething so separate instances should be present

Comment: Maybe you can use an ObjectPool where threads cooperatively check out and return instances?

Comment: Seems the only reasonable solution. I hoped something less complicated would be available